# Call jquery plugin after html load using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

On my project, I need to styling input radio button, so I use jquery uniform plugin. But on this page, radio button display after some Ajax loaded. I don't have permission to edit the form and Ajax function, so I can't use like knockout or data-hook. The result is radio button just like as usual.
How can I call that plugin, after radio button display without editing Ajax function or that form?
Sorry for my bad English. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {`, as `$(document).ready(function() {` will trigger before the ajax function has loaded the additional content.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that your javascript function runs before your html is done loading.

I think the [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function can help you

Comment: my function run on $(document).ready(). $(document).ready($( input[type="radio"]').uniform();) But it worked only on normal radio button. I mean not load after Ajax function. :D

Comment: Try `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {`